# Enlarge an image on mouseover in Popup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, visual-studio-2012

Hi all I've looked through several of these forum posts with different solutions but can't seem to get it. My style

```
<Style x:Key="ScaleStyle" TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2.5" ScaleY="2.5"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

My UniformGrid with images:

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="11" Name="Thumbnails">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="5"/>                               
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>                             
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Style="{StaticResource ScaleStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="{Binding}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="3">

                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

What happens with this is that the image gets bigger but inside the uniform grid which makes it overlap with other images and is just not nice looking.

On the other hand I tried using a tooltip popup and it would open a new popup but the image inside would be a giant zoom of the corner of the image.

```
<Image Name="Image" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Tulips.jpg" Height="100"
Stretch="Uniform">
<Image.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,7,5,5">
            <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Stretch="None" />
        </Border>
    </ToolTip>
</Image.ToolTip>
```

The problem might be that the original images are very large and in the Uniform grid i set the width and height to a 100 which makes them look like thumbnails but the tooltip seems to reference the original width and height and starts from a corner until it fits the width and height of the tooltip popup which ends up just showing a small part of the original very large picture.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set the image `Stretch` property to `fill`, that should resize the image to your container.
As for enlarging the images, you should try to create a named style for your images with a trigger that will enlarge them on mouse over.

Comment: I have a named stile that uses storyboards but what happens is when I set the style the images don't grow in a separate container, they aren't in a pop up, they grow inside the uniformgrid and end up overlapping.

Comment: Mind putting your named style in the question as well ? I don't think I can help much more than that but it could help other to answer your question faster

Comment: You've actually helped a great deal. It was the stretch property I was setting it on the original image instead of the tooltip image like the idiot I was and nothing was happening. But when I set it to the tooltip image it worked. Now thing is I'm not crazy about this solution I'd rather use a style but if you set your comment as question ill set it as Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `Stretch` property of the image to `fill` will make your image resize to the size of your container.