# Enlarge Image in Image label on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have image like this:

```
<Image Height="180" Width="180" Source="{Binding Result}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

How to enlarge (zoom) image in this label on mouse over? In easiest way as possible. I want edit `Image` from above. I want to enlarge image in this label and to stay in this size (`180*180`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enlarge an image on mouseover in Popup in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037461/enlarge-an-image-on-mouseover-in-popup-in-wpf)

Comment: My problem is less complex than mentioned in this duplicate

Comment: Do you want to enlarge the image (so its larger than 180*180) or do you want to zoom the image (so it's still 180*180, but zoomed in so you see a smaller portion of the image)?

Comment: The second, so i want the label stay to 180*180 but zoomed so i will see a smaller part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `Image` in a fixed-`size` Grid, apply a `ScaleTransform` to it and animate the latter. Something like this:

```
<Grid Height="180" Width="180">
    <Image Height="180" Width="180" Source="{Binding Result}" Grid.Column="1">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" CenterX="90" CenterY="90" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                             To="3.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                             To="3.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                             To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                             To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```